# Anonymous function - cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I am trying to use the strategy pattern to have different methods for generating actions from a list of input.

```
use rand::{prelude::SliceRandom, Rng};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Inner {
    num: usize,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Outer {
    ActionA(Inner),
    ActionB(Inner),
}

fn main() {
    // A method to generate an Outer from a list of Inners
    type Strategy = Box<dyn Fn(&Vec<&Inner>) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> Outer>>;

    let random_strategy: Strategy = Box::new(|inners| {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        Box::new(move || {
            let inner = inners.choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
            if rng.gen_bool(1.0 / 2.0) {
                Outer::ActionA(inner.to_owned().clone())
            } else {
                Outer::ActionB(inner.to_owned().clone())
            }
        })
    });

    let inners = vec![&Inner { num: 3 }, &Inner { num: 4 }];
    let get_choice = random_strategy(&inners);

    for _ in 0..4 {
        let choice = get_choice();
        println!("{:?}", choice);
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Each strategy is a closure because it may contain some state (not shown here in order to keep the example simple).

I get the compiler error

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
expected `(&&Vec<&Inner>, &mut ThreadRng)`
   found `(&&Vec<&Inner>, &mut ThreadRng)`
but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
expected `Box<(dyn FnMut() -> Outer + 'static)>`
   found `Box<dyn FnMut() -> Outer>`
```

I'm confused as to why the output `Outer` must have a static lifetime. I am creating `Outer` once, using a wholly-owned `Inner` (after cloning), returning it from the anonymous function, and never using it again in that anonymous function. I would expect that the caller (`let choice = get_choice()`) would have ownership over `Outer`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109062/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-automatic-coercion-due-to-conflicting-r) question has the same error but differs because, in my example, `Outer` needs to own `Inner`.

I can change the strategy definition to

```
type Strategy<'a> = Box<dyn Fn(&'a Vec<&'a Inner>) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> Outer>>;
```

but then I get the error

```
`inners` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enoughrustcE0597
main.rs(38, 1): `inners` dropped here while still borrowed
main.rs(18, 26): type annotation requires that `inners` is borrowed for `'static`
```

(Line 38 is the end of the main function)

I'm unsure how to fix this without cloning the entirety of inners each time I want to use a strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```rust
        move || {
            let inner = inners.choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
            if rng.gen_bool(1.0 / 2.0) {
                Outer::ActionA(inner.to_owned().clone())
            } else {
                Outer::ActionB(inner.to_owned().clone())
            }
        }
```

captures `inners`, which is the `&Vec<&Inner>` you passed in to the outer closure. `inners` is not bounded by `'static`, so the closure as a whole cannot be coerced to `dyn FnMut() -> Outer`, which is *implicitly* `dyn (FnMut() -> Outer) + 'static`.

To fix this, you can allow the Strategy to return a function that isn't `'static`, by redefining the type like so:

```rust
type Strategy = Box<
    dyn for<'a>
        Fn(&'a Vec<&'a Inner>) -> Box<dyn (FnMut() -> Outer) + 'a>
>;
```

Note the `for<'a>`. This is the trait-bound syntax equivalent to declaring a function like

```rust
fn example_strategy<'a>(&'a Vec<&'a Inner>) -> Box<dyn (FnMut() -> Outer) + 'a> {...}
```

where the function output has a lifetime depending on the input.

With this change, and adding a missing `mut` qualifier (calling a `FnMut` requires mutable access to the function), your program will compile.

Maybe you want the `FnMut() -> Outer` to stay `'static`; in that case, you'd need to define `Strategy` so that it *owns* the `Inner`s, with corresponding changes to how you call it. But you probably don't want this since you mentioned not cloning the `Inner`s; I'm mentioning it for comparison.

```rust
type Strategy = Box<dyn Fn(Vec<Inner>) -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> Outer>>;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Why was that last addition of `mut` necessary to `let mut get_choice...`? Was it because it was an `FnMut` or did it have something to do with the added lifetime?

Comment: @user82395214 Yes, calling a `FnMut` requires mutable access to the function, that's all.